# LibGDX Screens changing inputprocessor

Tags: android, input, touch, libgdx, screen

I am working on a new game and I am implementing Screens with LibGDX.

I've been a bit stuck about screen in combination with touches.

I have this in my render method:

```
if (Gdx.input.isTouched()) {
game.setScreen(new GameScreen(game));
dispose();
}
```

At the moment I have 4 different screens and they all change when isTouch is fired, the problem is that it goes from screen 1 to 4 after I touched the first Screen once.
I have tried to set the inputprocessor to null but it still hops from screen 1 till 4 without waiting at each screen. It seems the touch on Screen 1 is automatically fired at Screen 2 3 and 4 also. How can I reset the inputprocessor or return it true before the next screen is loaded so it won't register the touch from screen 1?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The static `Gdx.input.isTouched()` does not rely on any `InputProcessor` being set.

Actually you do not jump directly from Screen 1 to Screen 4. It goes 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4, but so fast that it *looks like* it would instantly jump to Screen 4. There is no multithreading here, there is always only one Screen at a time active.

Let all your screens `implement InputProcessor` and change the screen in the `touchUp` method. In your `Screen.show()` method you will set the active input processor to the current screen and in `Screen.hide()` you set it to `null`. That way you only change the screen *once* per touch and not in every frame as long as the screen `isTouched()`.